# How to use CSS to make the photos in a link match the proportions?

Tags: java, html, jquery, css

I have a problem, my English is not very good, but I try to describe it completely.

At present, there is a picture in href in a label, and a big picture will be opened after clicking it!
However, the currently displayed pictures in the href in the label are not the same in different devices. I want to adjust the settings of the pictures in this link so that the pictures inside can match the proportions?

I have tried the following settings:

```
background-position:center center;
background-size: cover;
object-fit:cover;
```

but still can’t adjust the proportion of the picture in the href in the label. I don’t know if anyone can help me. Thank you all for watching in advance.

Program example

https://codepen.io/hong-wei/pen/vYmWazP?editors=1100

Comment: Are yu saying that the demo-s which is currently set at 30px by 30px should show the image with its proportions? Is this to be inside that square (which is quite small) or is it to stretch div - if so either width or height?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `width: 300px`,

try

```
width: absolute;
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for telling me!
Is this the setting?

But the image size in the label seems to become uncontrollable?

Comment: https://codepen.io/hong-wei/pen/vYmWazP?editors=1100

Comment: width: absolute is not AFAIK a CSS setting

Answer (score 1):

From the code you have given, where the thumbnail (demo-s) container size is fixed at 30px by 30px it looks as though you want the image to cover that, which would be a quite usual way for a thumbnail - so all thumbnails stay the same size but may show only the central part of their image.

If this is what you want then try:

```
.demo-s img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

If not, could you explain a bit more what you want the thumbnails to look like?